# Reading ped file in c++.

Tags: c++, libraries, readfile

Is there any C++ library to read ped files (http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/data.shtml#ped)?

Comment: Downvoters: give a reason.

Comment: The reason is in the downvote button tooltip: Lack of effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can read ped file by https://github.com/fadern/libplinkio. But it read the ped file in binary format. That too when file is converted to transposed binary format. Normally in ped format the genotypes are coded as either A,G,C,T or 1,2,3,4. This represent raw sequence. libplinkio library uses a 0/1/NA coding for major/minor/missing allele. This can be cone by using plink http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/download.shtml 
plink --make-bed ...

Answer (score 4):

#### Conversion from PED to BED file

```
To convert myPlinkTextData.ped and myPlinkTextData.map in Plink binary format, use Plink as follows:
plink --file myPlinkTextData --make-bed --out myPlinkBinaryData
```

Source: http://www.shapeit.fr/pages/m02_formats/pedmap.html

#### Library for reading BED files

https://github.com/fadern/libplinkio (from vinash85 comment)

Reading PED-files seems to be on the roadmap (1.0), but I couldn't find any info on when or if 1.0 will be reached.

#### Write your own PED-file library

The source code for the `plink` command line tool is available:

[http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/download.shtml](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/%7Epurcell/plink/download.shtml)

So if you need a single library that does it all, you can take parts of it, and parts of `libplinkio` and combine them.

Comment: There is this library which does this job (https://github.com/fadern/libplinkio). The thing hat is needed first is to convert ped files to bed format.